# Reliably closing client sockets in a thread pool on shutdown

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, threadpool

I have a simple ServerSocket-based java program which accepts a client connection and puts it in a threadpool (ThreadPoolExecutor):

```
while() {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    pool.submit(new Client(socket)); // Client is a Runnable
}
```

Problem is when I try to shutdown the program and client threads stay around until the connection is closed on the other end (the jvm does not exit until then).

I could try to maintain all client objects and close all their sockets when server is about to shutdown. But I have no clue how maintain them? Especially removing them when done.

I tried [beforeExecute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable)) etc, but that only gives me another object (a FutureTask), not the Client object I'm looking for.

**Update:**

The problem is not adding sockets to a list, the problem is removing them when they are done as there are no way (afaik) to use afterExecute for that.

Comment: if you don't want the threads to hold up shutdown, then you can make them daemon threads.

Comment: Thanks but in this case I'd like an orderly shutdown of the clients.

Comment: then you should call shutdown on the Executor and handle the InterruptedExeception in the Runnable implementations.

Comment: No, that does not work since clients are blocking on I/O (socket). Streams are not interrupted.

Comment: you have two options then: use daemon threads or put timeouts on your socket connections.  the latter will allow you to periodically check the current interrupt status and attempt an orderly shutdown (but it will delay shutdown by the timeout value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to to have the Client return *itself* (in the Future) when done. Just need a list and then use the afterExecute method.

Like this:

```
pool =new ThreadPoolExecutor(...) {
    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        // The future returns the Client object!
        client = (Client)((FutureTask)r).get();
        // Remove it from list of known clients
        clients.remove(client);

    }
};

while() {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    Client client = new Client(socket)

    // Submit to pool, using client as the future return value          
    pool.submit(client, client);
    // Add to list of known clients
    clients.add(client);
}

// When app is closing
private shutdown() {
    for(Client client : clients){
        client.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store all the sockets in a `List` before submitting them to the pool.  Then the shutdown thread can call `close()` on all the sockets, which should cause the blocked threads to throw `SocketException`s.

Comment: Adding clients to the list is easy, but removing is not since I don't know when they are done. Afaik, there is no way with a pool to know that.

Comment: @MartinWickman Your Client class can add its socket to the list when it starts, and remove it from the pool when it closes the socket.

Comment: @EJP Yep, that is probably the best way. Also see my answer for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Call shutdownInput() on all the client sockets. That will cause the associated threads to *think* that the peer has disconnected and so exit gracefully.